# Flux of the vector field

Tags: calculus

Find the ﬂux of the vector ﬁeld
$$F = 12\langle12xy + 3z^2x + \sin(yz), x^2z + e^{xz}, 9x^2z + \ln(y^2 + 1)\rangle$$
across the closed surface $S$ formed by the surface $x = \sqrt{1- y^2 - z^2}$ (the front hemisphere with $0 \le \phi \le \pi$, $−\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$) and the plane $x = 0$.

I need to know the entire process, I'm not sure where to even start.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)?

Answer (score 1):

Use divergence theorem. 
$$
\oint_S \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf n\ dS = \iiint_\Omega \nabla \cdot \mathbf F\ dV
$$
$$
\nabla \cdot F = F_x + F_y + F_z = 12 \left (\left [12y + 3z^2 \right] + 0 + 9 x^2\right ) = 36 \left( 3x^2 + 4y + z^2\right )
$$
So, given surface integral is
\begin{align}
I &= \iiint_\Omega 36 \left( 3x^2 + 4y + z^2\right ) dV = \\
& =36 \int_0^1 \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{\frac \pi 2} \int_0^\pi \left( 3r^2 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \phi + 4r \sin \theta \sin \phi + r^2 \cos^2 \theta \right ) r^2 \sin \theta\ d\phi\ d\theta\ dr
\end{align}
Can you take it from here? It might be little bit tedious, but completely doable. You can start by splitting it into 3 integrals.

Comment: how did you get the 3r^2 sin^2..... ?

Comment: @user146949 Isn't that $3x^2$?